# How do I insert variables within html in a php array?

Tags: php, html, variables, zurb-foundation, orbit

EDIT: I've updated this question with the working code, but I've left the content of the text alone so you can see what I was trying to do in the future and also because there were a few other things I wanted to do aside of the initial question.

I have an array that has an html list in it, the php is shuffling the list to echo a random order. Within the list items in the array, I want to include a php variable, right now this is what I have:

```
<?php include('includes/header_topright_content.php'); ?>
<ul data-options="animation:fade; slide_number:false; pause_on_hover:false; timer_speed:5500; navigation_arrows:false; next_on_click:true; timer:true; bullets:false;" data-orbit>

<?php
    $links = array(
        '<li data-orbit-slide="headline-1"><img /><div>'.$Slide1.'</div></li>',
        '<li data-orbit-slide="headline-2"><img /><div>'.$Slide2.'</div></li>',
        '<li data-orbit-slide="headline-3"><img /><div>'.$Slide3.'</div></li>',
    );
    shuffle($links);

    foreach ($links as $link) { echo $link; }
?>
</ul>
```

I could have up to 10 or even 20 of these slides. The information the variables are linking to would be from a separate .php page that I "included." The information on that page is:

```
<?php
$Slide1 = "<h5>Slide 1</h5><h6>This is the content for slide 1!</h6>";
$Slide2 = "<h5>Slide 2</h5><h6>This is the content for slide 2!</h6>";
$Slide3 = "<h5>Slide 3</h5><h6>This is the content for slide 3!</h6>";
?>
```

If I scrap the variable idea and insert the html directly into the list item it works perfectly. If I try to put the variables in there, the slide will just be blank. I'm stuck on where to go from here, I'm great with html and css, but not so good with php, so any help is appreciated! I'm also open to any formatting tips and best practices, the cleaner the better.

Thanks in advance!

MORE INFO: There's a few complications behind as to why I'm looking to do this. The orbit image slider doesn't support a random order, and I found it much easier to just use php to randomize the order of the list items. The reason I want to use variables in these list items is because I'm using a cms (CouchCMS) to make that content editable - a simple solution would be to insert editable tags around that content, but that would only make one page editable, and this content is going to be 'included' in the header of every page. So I'm trying to find a way to put those variables on a separate page (I know 'including' it doesn't do that - maybe I can link it to the page like a css or js file?) to make that editable. If anyone has any ideas for this I'm open!

Comment: With string [concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With string [concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), your also need to include the variables file before assigning them variables to the array. You also dont need to wrap PHP variables in quotes when echoing.

```
<?php include('includes/variables.php'); ?>

<ul data-options="[orbit options go here]" data-orbit>
<?php
    $links = array(
        '<li data-orbit-slide="headline-1"><img /><div>'.$Slide1.'</div></li>',
        '<li data-orbit-slide="headline-2"><img /><div>'.$Slide2.'</div></li>',
        '<li data-orbit-slide="headline-3"><img /><div>'.$Slide3.'</div></li>',
    );
    shuffle($links);

    foreach ($links as $link) { echo $link; } //<<< notice no quotes
?>
</ul>
```

### Edit:

Can I make a suggestion to your code, by assigning to a slides array directly be it in an external file or not, you will be able to eventually dynamically or easily add new slides to the slider and not need to hard code into a second sub array before the loop. So something like. Also by changing to alternative syntax your keep a nice HTML structure.

```
<?php
$slide[] = "<h5>Slide 1</h5><h6>This is the content for slide 1!</h6>";
$slide[] = "<h5>Slide 2</h5><h6>This is the content for slide 2!</h6>";
$slide[] = "<h5>Slide 3</h5><h6>This is the content for slide 3!</h6>";

shuffle($slide);
?>

<ul data-options="animation:fade; slide_number:false; pause_on_hover:false; timer_speed:5500; navigation_arrows:false; next_on_click:true; timer:true; bullets:false;" data-orbit>
<?php foreach ($slide as $key=>$value):?>
    <li data-orbit-slide="headline-<?php echo $key?>"><img /><div><?php echo $value; ?></div></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, it still won't show the content in the variables for me though, I'm not sure why?

Comment: http://mrobertsdesign.ca/g2drivers/ - here is my temporary testing url... the space at the very top in the middle (between the logo on the left and the calendar-like list on the right) is supposed to be a content slider, and it technically works, but while using variables it won't show anything.

Comment: Yeah, variables need setting before using. include is just like as-if the files code is inline code

Comment: It will only show the last variable (Slide3) at this point, the rest are blank. There must be something wrong with that file?

Comment: I can see there being outputted in the DOM (source) so the PHP is working, it might be the javascript or the structure the javascript expects.

Comment: If I put that html content in the LI instead of using variables it works fine. I wouldn't think it would be that big of a difference, but that is interesting. - now it's up without the variables, so it really shouldn't make a difference

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact code your using now, it seems as if the PHP vars in `includes/variables.php` are empty except 3

Comment: Dooh moment ahead ;p check the variables in `includes/variables.php` your overwriting them, there all `$Slide1`

Comment: Lol ugh, we'll just pretend this didn't happen hahaha

Comment: You solved the question haha, but is it possible to link that page as if it were a css or js file ( <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" /> or <script src="js/script.js"></script> )? So far I don't think it works like that though.

Comment: Thank you very much =) I don't usually have much of a need to use PHP but now I'm running into situations where using it actually makes sense for me lol, so I'm trying to learn, but I'm gonna be on this site a lot =p